# "Error Loading Page" message, show error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developping my first MVC4 application and have now on several occasions gotten a 'Error loading page' message. This is nice if you're in a production environment but when developing an application it would be much more productive to see what's wrong, see the exception details. Is there some way or setting to get to the exception information wich causes this message ?

regards,
Jurjen.

Answer (score 1):

It its a .Net exception locate the `customErrors`element in your Web.config and set the attribute `mode="Off"` or `mode="RemoteOnly"`.

If its a javascript error open your javascript console and watch for errors.

If its a .Net exception but the YSOD isn't rendered by the browser because it was requested via ajax, the fastet way to get to the output is to use a debugging proxy like fiddler and watch the html result there.

If its neither of the options, you have to provide more details.
Have you ever tried to run the application in the debugger?

Comment: This settings has no effect, I already tried that when Dennis suggested it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jurjen i have added some options to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can enable debugging and set the error display mode in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" ...>
        ...
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="On|Off|RemoteOnly" ...> 
        (set this to Off or RemoteOnly) when debugging
        ...
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

- [**How to enable debugging for ASP.NET applications**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8z01xdh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [**How to set the `customErrors` Element**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm aware of these settings (I have developped many sites using web-forms), but these settings have no effect on my problem wich seems to be coming from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

in _layout set

> $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

This solved my problem

Cheers